# Constant subroutine being redefined due to module being loaded multiple times; how to debug?

Tags: perl, module, constants

Well, I'm not new to Perl or Perl modules, but still I might have made some stupid bug that I cannot find:

I'm developing some code consisting of multiple modules, and some modules are used multiple times in different modules.
Typically I use `use module;` to load a module.
The program where the problem occurs is rather complex, so I cannot include it here.
Also, it seems the problem started after having added a new module.
Still I cannot find a bug in that new module, nor in the modules using it.

I'm trying to sketch the use pattern with the module named `H` (for *helper*) here (all module names are simplified here).
I have a module `C` (for constants) that uses some base module `B`.
`H` uses `C`, but it also uses `B`.
And I have a module `X::Y::H` that uses `H` (directly and also via `@ISA`) and `C` (as well as `B`).

When `H` is loaded there is no problem, and I find an entry for `H` in `%INC`.
But then I see the exporter part of `H` being executed.
Then I see another `use H` being called from `X::Y::H` (maybe even twice).
Then after the next step in the debugger (I used `$DB::single = 1`) I get those errors about constants in `H` being redefined.

Maybe it's important to know that I'm using `-I` commandline switches to locate my modules, like `-I . -I ./lib -I ../..`.
Could the relative paths possibly play a role there, or the fact that two modules have the same name "at the leaf" (`H` and `X::Y::H`)?

Single-stepping in the debugger did not help me to find the problem, so I'm somewhat clueless, even thinking it might be a Perl bug.

How could I debug (and fix (once the problem is known)) the issue?

Having added `BEGIN { print "Loading " . __PACKAGE__ . "\n" }` and `BEGIN { print "Loaded " . __PACKAGE__ . "\n" }` at beginning and end of the module in question, respectively, I see that the module `H` is actually loaded a second time, and the stream of errors follows the "Loading ..." message.

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue:

Basically it was module `H`: I had moved `H` into a subdirectory like `S/H.pm` within the project directory, and I included `S` via `-I S`, but I forgot to adjust the package name inside `H.pm` and some modules using it.

So Perl loaded `H.pm`, but in `%INC` it was stored as `S/H.pm`, so (I guess) a `use H;` would search for a `H.pm` again as `%INC` "only" contained `S/H.pm`.

Thus `H.pm` (found via the include paths I had specified) was loaded a second time, causing the bad effects.

After fixing the include paths and all `use` occurrences of `H`, the error was gone.

Comment: Indeed. `use`, `package` and the file name must all agree, or weird stuff happens :)